# VBA Excel - Use VBA even if the sheets are protected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently in a process of using the VBA code even if the sheets are protected. May I ask if what is the best approach to this matter?

While researching,  I found these answers, but I don't know if should I use them in every procedure or is there an easy way for this?

```
Sub Edit_Sheet1()
    'Unprotect Sheet1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect

    'Do Something to Sheet1

    'Reprotect Sheet1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect
End Sub
```

I don't understand how the code below works but in the [article](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/unprotect-protect-worksheets/) where I saw this, it says that `You can use the UserInterFaceOnly setting. When TRUE, worksheets will ONLY be protected from users, NOT from VBA.`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Next ws
End Sub
```

I'm new to this VBA thing so I'll be happy if someone can help me to figure out what's the best way to do this.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me... If you want the ability for VBA to make modifications then use the second code. I guess that makes it "the best way" - is that your question? Here's more you can use to decide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect

Comment: @braX correct me if I'm wrong but if I use the second code, I only need to put it in the `ThisWorkbook` file, right? And then even if the sheets are locked, the VBA codes will run? Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's how I understand it. Have you tried it to see if that's right?

Comment: @braX I'm still figuring it out, but it seems to work now. I just forget to put the password that's why it's not working earlier. Thanks for helping and for giving the reference, it helps!